# MS-Access combo box control source

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

Is it possible to use an IIf statement in the control source of a combo box?  I have a combo box that I want to pull a series of names from the associated table if their position is like "Ops".  Here is what I have tried in the control source for the combo box.

```
=IIf(Roster!Position Like "Ops*",Roster!Last,"")
```

I am fairly sure it is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Mods based on feedback from HansUp

SQL for query

```
SELECT Roster.Last
FROM Roster
WHERE (((Roster.Position) Like "Ops*"))
GROUP BY Roster.Last;
```

Combo Box: Supervisor

```
Control Source
=Supervisor!Last
```

Still returns no data.

Comment: is there an error or the output is wrong?

Comment: Marc, when I click the drop arrow there are no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have a combo box that I want to pull a series of names from the associated table if their position is like "Ops".*

Use a query as the combo's Row Source.

```
SELECT [Last], [another field ?]
FROM Roster
WHERE Position Like "Ops*";
```

Then the combo's Control Source can be a query field.

Comment: HansUp, I have created the query as described and set the control source to the query but still nothing.  I am modifying the original post to show the changes.

Comment: HansUp, I forgot to add.  SELECT Supervisor.Last FROM Supervisor;  to the Row Source...  It works fine now.  THanks!